# Libgdx often low fps after android device resume

Tags: android, libgdx

When i run my application written in libgdx (and every other app which is using libgdx, even those from google market) its often displayed at 25-30 FPS and it should be 60 FPS by default.

Sometimes it is just fine and displays at 60 fps but after i quit and enter app again or just pause/resume it randomly displays at 25-30 fps or 60 fps. It happens only on my android device (desktop is fine) 2.3.6 (Samsung Galaxy S Advance) When i run it on Ainol HERO 10 there is no problem with that.

Here is my code which i've written for testing this issue:

```
public class FpsTest implements ApplicationListener{
    OrthographicCamera cam;
    ShapeRenderer shapeRenderer;
    SpriteBatch batcher;
    BitmapFont bf;

    public void create() {
        bf = new BitmapFont();
        cam = new OrthographicCamera();
        cam.setToOrtho(false, Gdx.graphics.getWidth()/4, Gdx.graphics.getHeight()/4);
        batcher = new SpriteBatch();
        batcher.setProjectionMatrix(cam.combined);
    }
    public void resize(int width, int height) {}
    public void render() {
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0,0.2f,0,1);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL30.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        batcher.begin();
        bf.draw(batcher, "FPS: "+String.valueOf(Gdx.graphics.getFramesPerSecond()), 35, 120);
        batcher.end();
    }
    public void pause() {}
    public void resume() {}
    public void dispose() {}
}
```

Also i did a short movie about my problem: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YjMr9fBYhHA&feature=youtu.be :)

Comment: Does this "Framedrop" take only a few seconds or does it stay for a longer time? How many programms are running in the background?

Comment: This: `"FPS: "+String.valueOf(Gdx.graphics.getFramesPerSecond())` is likely to create garbage, causing the GC to kick in every now and then. Try to use a StringBuilder instead (the one that comes with libgdx). Also, having an (almost) empty render method might cause the device to lower the framerate to save battery life.

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/libgdx/issues/detail?id=1024

Answer (score 0):

As the [official API documentation](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/Graphics.html#getFramesPerSecond%28%29) points out, `Gdx.graphics.getFramesPerSecond()` returns an averaged value.

You cannot rely on that for an accurate framerate report. Use `Gdx.graphics.getRawDeltaTime()` instead, then calculate it's inverse to convert it to FPS.

Comment: It doesnt matter if i use .getFramesPerSecond() or .getRawDeltaTime() and calculate FPS from it. Its always pretty much the same result. Also its not only showing lower FPS, animation is also acting like its displayed in lower frame rate.